# How to get the Ping sensor data to Android Studio on a TextView via Blutooth HC-06

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I have managed to set up the connection between my arduino and the App with the help of [Instructables blog](http://www.instructables.com/id/Android-Bluetooth-Control-LED-Part-2/?ALLSTEPS). 
The connection is set but i need the sensor output value of the ardunio to be displayed on a TextView. This is the Arduino [code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping).
How do i program my Android studio program to read the output value of the serial monitor in the Arduino?

Comment: If you haven't already, you'll need to set up a way to receive data from the arduino. You can then set your textview to that value. This tutorial should give you all the information you need. 
https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the tutorial shows how send data from the app to arduino, but not how receive data from the arduino to your app for do this, you will need:

1. Send data from arduino by HC-06.
2. Receive and decode your data in the app.
3. show decoded data in the TextView.

a litle example for do this.

In Arduino:
can be the example of the arduino page you must only make sure that HC-06 is properly connected in Serial port.

In the app code you can use this code to receive data, only change the name of SocketBT instance, for the instance that you need.

```
 private class TareaLeer extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(SocketBT.isConnected())
        {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = SocketBT.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                inputStream.read(buffer);
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                }
                String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                String Recepcion = strInput;

                Log.d("Recibi",Recepcion);
                //Here you can pass the value of recepcion to any globlal variable and show in TextView

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    Parar();
    }
}
```

for show it on TextView you can do this.

```
MyTextView.setText(Recepcion);
```

this is a very general explanation, for do it , you need know how android code works basically, but is a good example for start Android and Arduino Programming.

Comment: hey, should i follow the code from the Instructables blog or the code given in the link by @Bone